# How to Parse a incomplete JSON like string

Tags: java, android, json

I am reading some data via BLE from my peripheral device to my android app. 
the app gets the data from BLE device in a JSON format. it all works fine, except in few cases when i get incomplete JSON string from BLE device (i have no control over that and i need to handle whatever i receive. Initially, i was getting a simple JSON array like

```
[wifi1, wifi2, wifi3, wifi4, wifi5]
```

So if get incomplete string i will handle JSON parse exception and use String Tokenizer and simply parse each token and get the wifi name

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(new String(bytes), ",");
        int size =  tokens.countTokens();
        HashMap<String, Object> map;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();   
            map.put("Wifi, tokens.nextToken().replace("\"", "").replace("]", "").replace("[", ""));
```

But now the JSON string has been changed and includes a lot of other information, this is the new JSON that i get

```
[{"ssid":"Wifi1","rssi":-50,"encrypt":"on"},{"ssid":"wifi2","rssi":-61,"encrypt":"on"},{"ssid":"wifi3","rssi":-81,"encrypt":"of
```

Now if i get incomplete JSON in this format (as above) i am not able to parse the wifi name and encrypt info using StringTokenizer (it's getting way complicated and ugly).
Do you have any idea on how to parse these wifi name and encrypt info from above string. Any suggestion will be of great help.

Comment: Just finish it off so it becomes valid JSON and reparse it

Comment: use `android.util.JsonReader`

Comment: @CaiusJard yeah  i thought of that , but i reach above code in JSON parse exception and updating JSON string and parsing it in JSON exception handling code will not work .

Comment: @pskink android.util.JsonReader can handle incomplete JSON ?

Comment: Use a *streaming* JSON parser. That way you'll get the values that can be parsed, before an exception is thrown. [`android.util.JsonReader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) is a streaming parser, so [advise by @pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897892/how-to-parse-a-incomplete-json-like-string#comment78754991_45897892) is good.

Comment: its like a reader, so you can read next tokens `while (reader.hasNext()) {`

Comment: @pskink thanks for suggestion, but in case of incomplete JSON even reader.hasNext() will throw an exception and it will not be possible to do reader.close without propagating the exception to calling function and loosing all the values parsed.

Comment: simply catch IOException

Comment: Yeah i have done that, its working i will post a working example soon. Thanks for your help pskink

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @pskink and @Andreas for suggesting streaming JSON parser, i tried this and it works for me. Hopefully it will be helpful for someone else as well.

```
 public void parseWifiJSON(byte[] bytes)
 {
   trackerWifiScanList = readJsonStream(bytes);
   // do stuff with your list
 } 

 public List<WifiScan> readJsonStream(byte[] bytes)  {

    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(new String(bytes)));
    List<WifiScan> resultList = null;
    try {
        resultList = readMessagesArray(reader);
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }
    }

    return resultList;
}

public List<WifiScan> readMessagesArray(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<WifiScan> messages = new ArrayList<WifiScan>();

    try {
        reader.beginArray();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            messages.add(readMessage(reader));
        }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.endArray();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }
    }
    return messages;
}

public WifiScan readMessage(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    String wifissid ="";
    int rssi = 0;
    String encrypt="";
    WifiScan wifInfo = new WifiScan();
    try {
        reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            String name = reader.nextName();
            if (name.equals("ssid")) {
                wifissid = reader.nextString();
            } else if (name.equals("rssi")) {
                rssi = reader.nextInt();
            } else if (name.equals("encrypt")) {
                encrypt = reader.nextString();
            } else {
                reader.skipValue();
            }
        }
        reader.endObject();
        wifInfo.setSsid(wifissid);
        wifInfo.setRssi(rssi);
        wifInfo.setEncrypt(encrypt);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        // JSON was not complete so just set a dummy object.
        wifInfo.setSsid("");
        wifInfo.setRssi(0);
        wifInfo.setEncrypt("");
    }
    return wifInfo;
}
```